# Stripping a string to build a new S3 path

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

In my project I am assigning individual UUIDs to every upload that gets moved between two folders in my S3 Bucket, for the purposes of individualising their links later on.

However, while attempting to format the Object Key as displayed in the method below, all the code below
`parts = old_key.split('/')` greys out/ no longer functions, indicating a Syntax error that I can't see.

```
def move_and_rename(target_folder, prefix_generator: nil)
    prefix_generator ||= -> { SecureRandom.uuid }
      s3_objects.each do |obj|
        prefix = prefix_generator.call
        old_key = obj.key
        parts = old_key.split('/')
        new_last_part = "#{prefix}-#{parts.last}”
        new_key = (parts[0..-2] + [new_last_part]).join('/')
        new_key = s3_folder ? obj.key.sub(s3_folder, target_folder) : (parts[0..-2] + [new_last_part]).join('/')


        obj.move_to(bucket: bucket_name, key: new_key)
      yield(old_key: old_key, new_key: new_key, obj: obj, prefix: prefix) if block_given?
    end
    self
  end
```

Or perhaps I have this structured completely wrong within the method? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `new_last_part = "#{prefix}-#{parts.last}”` look at the last character, it should be `"`, but is a Right Double Quotation Mark `”`

Comment: A _syntax error_ means that Ruby can't interpret your code which usually indicates a typo. It has nothing to do with AWS or how your code is structured.

Comment: BTW, make sure to turn off "smart quotes" when coding.

Comment: @Stefan what programming editor would do such a thing? Somehow I don't think they wrote this code in MS Word.